# Why does mysql make delete offset?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am implementing database(College project).
I came across innodb diagrams in github

[image]

I see that we maintain a delete chain why we wanna do this because if we write the whole block (because it if more efficient write whole block ) back why don't just simply delete that record.

And what is the use of maintaining delete chain.As we can see they use linked list so deleting the whole record requires no extra cost. Please explain or tell me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just delete an item from a B-tree. You have to ensure that the fundamental B-tree condition still holds, which may involve merging adjacent nodes, which will leave one node left over, which you have to know about, so you have to put it into a free list for later reuse, so that you don't just keep growing the file indefinitely.

If you're talking about records, you still have to know where the deleted records are, for reuse. There is no such thing as 'just delet[ing] the record'.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responses I got answer by asking at dba.stackexcahnge.com by user Károly Nagy .Reason is that if we are in transaction we can not simple delete record .If transaction is done then we can delete the deleted record.Link to answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121919/why-does-mysql-make-delete-offset